# Set's contains method returns different value at different time

Tags: swift, iequatable, hashable

I was thinking about how Swift ensures uniqueness for Set because I have turned one of my obj from `Equatable` to `Hashable` for free and so I came up with this simple Playground

```
struct SimpleStruct: Hashable {
    let string: String
    let number: Int

    static func == (lhs: SimpleStruct, rhs: SimpleStruct) -> Bool {
        let areEqual = lhs.string == rhs.string
        print(lhs, rhs, areEqual)
        return areEqual
    }
}

var set = Set<SimpleStruct>()
let first = SimpleStruct(string: "a", number: 2)
set.insert(first)
```

So my first question was:

Will the `static func ==` method be called anytime I insert a new obj inside the set?

My question comes from this thought:

For `Equatable` obj, in order to make this decision, the only way to ensure two obj are the same is to ask the result of `static func ==`.

For `Hashable` obj, a faster way is to compare `hashValue`s... but, like in my case, the default implementation will use both `string` and `number`, in contrast with `==` logic.

So, in order to test how `Set` behaves, I have just added a print statement.

I have figured out that sometimes I got the print statement, sometimes no. Like sometimes `hashValue` isn't enough in order to make this decision ... So the method hasn't been called every time. 
Weird...

So I've tried to add two objects that are equal and wondering what will be the result of `set.contains`

```
let second = SimpleStruct(string: "a", number: 3)
print(first == second) // returns true
set.contains(second)
```

And wonders of wonders, launching a couple of times the playground, I got different results and this might cause unpredictable results ...
Adding

```
var hashValue: Int {
    return string.hashValue
}
```

it gets rid of any unexpected results but my doubt is:

Why, without the custom `hashValue` implementation, `==` sometimes gets called and sometimes it doesn't?
Should Apple avoid this kind of unexpected behaviours?

[image: Returns false]
[image: returns true]

Comment: Your implementation violates the rule that equal instances **must** have the same hash value. Therefore “unexpected behaviour” is to be expected ...

Comment: Shouldn't your `==` function compare both the string and number? Right now you can have two structs with the same string but different numbers yet your `==` treats them as equal. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Just to make it clear. My question was: Why the `static func ==` sometimes gets called and sometimes it doesn't. Of course if `hashValue` and `==` implementation uses different properties, I will have unexpected behaviours but I'm wondering why sometimes `hashValue` isn't enough and the compiler has to ask to `==` in order to get the right answer

Comment: Roughly speaking, a set uses a number  of “buckets” to store its elements. The hash value is used to determine in which bucket the value would be stored. Then each element in the bucket is compared with `==` agains the value that you search. – But that is an implementation detail, and may change at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synthesized implementation of the `Hashable` requirement uses all stored
properties of a `struct`, in your case `string` and `number`. Your implementation
of `==` is only based on the string:

```
let first = SimpleStruct(string: "a", number: 2)
let second = SimpleStruct(string: "a", number: 3)

print(first == second) // true
print(first.hashValue == second.hashValue) // false
```

This is a violation of a requirement of the [`Hashable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable) protocol:

> Two instances that are equal must feed the same values to Hasher in hash(into:), in the same order.

and causes the undefined behavior. (And since hash values are randomized
since Swift 4.2, the behavior can be different in each program run.)

What *probably* happens in your test is that the hash value of `second`  is used to determine the “bucket” of the set in which the value
would be stored. That may or may not be the same bucket in which `first` is stored. – But that is an implementation detail: Undefined behavior is undefined behavior, it can cause unexpected results or even
runtime errors.

Implementing

```
var hashValue: Int {
    return string.hashValue
}
```

or alternatively (starting with Swift 4.2)

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(string)
}
```

fixes the rule violation, and therefore makes your code behave as expected.